# Align UIImage vertically center

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to align an image vertically central using Swift. I understand you do this by using constraints, however I've been unable to get this to work.

```
func getLogo() {
    let logo = UIImage(named: "LogoWhite")
    let logoView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.addSubview(logoView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use constraints (I personally do not like them) you can check for container center and put your `UIImageView` there.

Example:

containerView -> the view that contains your `logo`

logo -> the view you want vertically centered

```
logo.center.y = containerView.center.y
```

If the containerView is the screen, then

```
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
let height = screen.height
logo.center.y = screen.height / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using extensions on UIView to make auto layout much easier. This seems like a lot of code to begin with for such a simple task but these convenience functions will make things a lot quicker in the long run for example:

```
public func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero){
        
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        //Set top, left, bottom and right constraints
        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }
        if let leading = leading {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }
        if let trailing = trailing {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }
        
        //Set size contraints
        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }
        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

Then you could simply call:

```
someUIView.anchor(anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16), size: .init(width: 80, height: 80))
```

Then to answer your question directly you could then add more extensions to do some stuff easily:

```
public func anchorCenterXToSuperview(constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let anchor = superview?.centerXAnchor {
            centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

**Finally you could then simply call `anchorCenterXToSuperview()` on any `UIView` to centre any object.**

Don't forget to make sure you've added your view to a view hierarchy before attempting to layout your views otherwise you'll get errors.